# Caching of function arguments in lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

A small code snippet from python 3.7.6 which completely has blown my mind:

```
def func(e, k):
    print(k + e)

for f in [lambda e: func(e, k) for k in ['T', 'E', 'K']]:
    for e in range(3):
        f(str(e))
```

As an output I get:

```
K0
K1
K2
K0
K1
K2
K0
K1
K2
```

Is it a bug or a feature of Python? Because if you replace `lambda` with `functools.partial` everything works as expected!

Comment: And what does it mean "as expected"? What would you like to see as output and how exactly the code with `functools.partial` looks like?

Comment: I would recommend to check out [Late Binding Closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Comment: Expectation is subjective, but the behaviour is as documented, there is a dupe somehwere